# Error when running dnsmasq executable on Android

Tags: lineageos

I am trying to build **dnsmasq** DNS filter on Android (**LineageOS**). This is what I am doing:

I download the code from here:
`https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/`

I downloaded the **Android NDK**. Then I export the necessary variables:

```
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/myuser/Library/Projects/dnsmasq-Android/android-ndk-r26b/
export ANDROID_NDK=/home/myuser/Library/Engineering/manuals/Android/dnsmasq/android-ndk-r26b/
export PATH=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

Now I am ready to compile. So I run:

```
../android-ndk-r26b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make clean
../android-ndk-r26b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/make ARCH=arm64-v8a
```

Now it compiles fine. So I copy the executable to the phone:

```
adb push dnsmasq /data/local/tmp/dnsmasq
adb shell 'chmod +x /data/local/tmp/dnsmasq'
adb shell '/data/local/tmp/dnsmasq --version'
```

When I run the last command, I get the error:
`/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/dnsmasq: not executable: 64-bit ELF file`

What is going wrong? I tried replacing the make architecture with 'arm64', 'arm64,v7a' but did not make a difference..

Comment: Before uploading the binary to the phone you can test the binary using `file` and/or `readelf` command regarding which platform /CPU architecture the executable is targeting.

Comment: Thank you. `file dnsmasq` gives this: `dnsmasq: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=2957f2a589e1b2e1d7ab9c97a89c9121a6bcd5f4, for GNU/Linux 4.4.0, not stripped` I have no experience with Android so I can't tell what's wrong about it..

Comment: As you can see you have built a 64bit version but not for arm but for x86. I am not a compiler expert but according to [this site](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems) the first path after `prebuilt` is the target tag thus it is no surprise you compiled the binary for `x86_64` and not for arm64-v8a.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but I still can't find the solution for this particular problem.. I found these instructions: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#non-autoconf_make_projects But none helped..